# Find all entries within a certain interval of each other in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I need to find all entries that are contained within a certain interval (error) from each other,  for each column of a pandas DataFrame (and group them by index). Example for a +/- 0.2 interval:

```
myDataFrame:
    A    B    C
0  1.1  1.3  1.5
1  0.7  0.1  -0.5
2  1.2  1.9  1.3
3  0.1  0.0  -0.3
4  0.2  0.1  -0.1
```

The result would be:

**Column A:** {0,2}, {3,4}

**Column B:** {1,3,4}

**Column C:** {0,2}, {1,3}, {3,4}

Is this possible? I know I could execute multiple *for* loops to iterate each row and column, I was just wondering if there is any way to do this using pandas because it would be much faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas cut function to bin the variables.

```
import pandas as pd    
df.loc[:, 'C_bins'] = pd.cut(df.C, bins=[.2*x for x in range(-10, 10)])
```

yields

```
     A    B    C        C_bins
0  1.1  1.3  1.5    (1.4, 1.6]
1  0.7  0.1 -0.5  (-0.6, -0.4]
2  1.2  1.9  1.3    (1.2, 1.4]
3  0.1  0.0 -0.3  (-0.4, -0.2]
4  0.2  0.1 -0.1     (-0.2, 0]
```

From there you can group them with `groupby` or count them with `value_counts`